# Unable to open PowerPoint File using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I like to open a PowerPoint file from Excel.
I have tried it several times but it does not work.

The Problem sounds similar to these:

[not able to Open Powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148410/not-able-to-open-powerpoint-using-vba)

The only difference is, I get another error code:

'Laufzeitfehler '-2147024894 (80070002)':
Die Methode 'Open' für das Objekt 'Presentations' ist fehlgeschlagen.

I checked that the Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library ist activated. And i checked the filepath several times.

Does anyone have an idea what the mistake can be?

```
Sub sub_powerpoint_test()
Dim ObjPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ObjPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim str_FileName_PPTX As String

Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ObjPPT.Visible = msoCTrue


'Get PPT Filename
If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.pptx")) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "PPTX file does NOT exist in this folder."
Else
     str_FileName_PPTX = ThisWorkbook.Path & Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.pptx")
     Debug.Print str_FileName_PPTX
 End If


Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open(str_FileName_PPTX, Untitled:=msoTrue)

End Sub
```

The error occures in the Open line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. The Problem was a missing "\" in the path.

The corrected code is:

```
If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.pptx")) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "PPTX file does NOT exist in this folder."
Else
    str_FileName_PPTX = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.pptx")
    Debug.Print str_FileName_PPTX
End If
```